# How to resolve Exhausted ResultSet prob.?

Tags: java, database, oracle10g, resultset

I am working with Oracle 10g using JAVA and I'm trying to work out the following code but it keeps on showing "Exhausted Resultset".. Does anyone know how can i get the proper output? Any help related to this would be appreciated...

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANTS");
ResultSet rs2 = stmt.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANCE"); 
String insert = ("INSERT INTO ATTENDANTS ( Attendant_Name, Attendant_Age, Attendant_Contact_No, Attendant_Department_Name, REGISTRATION_NUM) VALUES('" + naam + "','" + umar + "','" + number + "', '" + deprt + "' , '" + registration + "')");
String insert2 = ("INSERT INTO ATTENDANCE ( Attendant_Name, Attendant_Age, Attendant_Contact_No, Attendant_Department_Name, REGISTRATION_NUM) VALUES('" + naam + "','" + umar + "','" + number + "', '" + deprt + "' , '" + registration + "')");
//ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
//boolean colname = rsmd.equals(rs.getString(1));
while(rs.next() || rs2.next()){
   int a = naam.compareTo(rs.getString(1));
   int b = naam.compareTo(rs2.getString(1));
   int c = registration.compareTo(rs.getString(5));
   int d = registration.compareTo(rs2.getString(7));
        if((naam.equals(rs.getString(1)) && name.equals(rs2.getString(1))) || (registration.equals(rs.getString(5)) && registration.equals(rs2.getString(7)))){
            System.out.println("Record Already Exist");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Name already exists in Record");
            //faceFrame.repaint();
            System.out.println("Already EXISTS");
        }
        //else if((a == 0 && c == 0) || (b == 0 && d == 0)){
        if((a == 0 && c == 0) || (b == 0 && d == 0)){
            stmt.executeQuery(insert);
            stmt.executeQuery(insert2);
            System.out.println("INSERTION DONE");
        }
       //else
       //System.out.println("Insertion Unsuccessfull");
    }
}
```

Comment: First, do you know that the two queries will return the same number of results?  If not, `rs.next() || rs2.next()` doesn't make a lot of sense-- if either of the result sets have no more rows, it doesn't make sense to try to fetch the data.  Your queries have no `order by` so it seems highly unlikely that you can just compare the n-th result from one against the n-th result of the other.  Your `insert` statement is also fixed before you enter the loop which seems highly unlikely to be right.  Plus, realistically, you should be doing this with a single insert statement rather than writing Java.

Comment: First, if you are going to change your code, edit your question.  Don't post code in comments.  Second, that does a Cartesian product between the two tables.  So if each table has 1000 rows, your query would return 1 million rows (1000000).  It seems unlikely that is what you want.  Your INSERT statement appears to make no sense-- you can only insert into one table at a time (well, you could write an `insert all` I guess).

Comment: @JustinCave thank you for pointing out these things.. I've rearranged my code and now it is working...